# GET request updating 'seen' status

Tags: http, post, web, get, request

First of all, I am aware of the details mentioned in the HTTP 1.1 specification saying GET requests should be idempotent, and it all makes total sense to me. I'm always using POST requests for login/logout, form updates and everything that changes the state of my web app, but I have a problem with one particular scenario.

Imagine you're displaying a list of user's notifications, and you want to update the seen status once they've been rendered into html. The simplest solution is to perform an update of the model instances during the GET request, but that's where it would break HTTP 1.1 specs. Not only it would not follow the specs, but I'm also concerned about url prefetching and automatic GET request retry in some browsers, and maybe other possible scenarios.

Doing it using AJAX also doesn't seem like a good enough solution to me, because I would like the web to also work correctly with JS disabled.

The site also has an API for iOS/Android, but there it can be easily solved in multiple ways which seem right to me, so that's not a problem.

Did you guys come across any similar problem to this and found a way to handle it? I can't seem to find a good solution to this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If requirement is 'update the seen status once they've been rendered into html', then why not AJAX? Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877641/how-ajax-application-should-behave-when-javascript-is-disabled-common-practice and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100721/ajax-disabled-javascript-do-you-worry and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25969/should-i-bother-to-develop-for-javascript-disabled

Comment: I'm always trying to make websites fully working also without JS, and if I implemented only the AJAX solution it would mean the notifications would never get marked as read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I found a solution which makes sense. I'm going to implement the AJAX solution (POST) + a 'Mark all as read' button (POST) as a fallback for the edge case.